# Hidden community of people who don't know they are disabled

Tags: story-identification, books

A book I read in the 90s in the UK. Probably written for young adults.

A hidden community where everyone is physically different.

One person has feathers. He brings in things from outside. One day he accidentally brings in a video of an athlete and they see that other peoples' bodies are symmetrical. The community realise they are the unusual ones and escape.

They end up at a rock concert... here my memory goes hazy. They turn out to be the children of some chemical disaster?

I've been trying to identify this for years!

Comment: My often comment: never heard of it but sounds intriguing.

Comment: That sounds tantalizingly familiar, complete with the escape having them pop out in the middle of a music event and initially being mistaken as being part of the spectacle.

Comment: I want to say that the children all have names that turn out to be three letter designations? Like we have Jayellam who is actually subject JLM.

Comment: Hmm... I think I was thinking of J. Hunter Holly's "The Others". But I haven't found any reference to the concert bit.

Comment: So I doubt it's  John Varley's "[The Persistence of Vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Persistence_of_Vision_(novella))", as the people in the hidden community are all blind and deaf, but you should consider it.

Comment: Zero overlap with the Varley story.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions.

@Fuzzyboots I just read The Others on archive.org. It is very similar in theme to the story I half remember, so I'm not surprised you thought of it. But the book I read was longer, a standalone short novel rather than a short story in a collection. Wouldn't be surprised if they'd been inspired by the earlier book.

Definitely not the Varley book.

Comment: Hmm... just to clarify, my vague memories of a similar story has it that, in the course of their escape, they open a door and find themselves in the middle of the rock concert, with the reveal kind of being that, rather than in some grand conspiracy, they've been locked inside a set of rooms, possibly by a small organization or individual, in a larger building that others reside in (it could also be there's something involving secret basements or passages, but I remember it as them going from captivity in "their world" to a room where the event is).

Comment: My memory is they got there in a van... but probably misremembered!

Comment: How large is the group?  When I first read the question I was imagining 20-50, but if they fit in a van it'd be more like 4-8.  How do they get food if they don't know what "normal" people look like?  How did they know how to drive a van?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I plead Valorum's Maxim.

Comment: @DavidW I think it was a community of dozens. I seem to remember only some escape, and someone disreputable has them in the van. But memories are fuzzy.